# Laravel set Attribute not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i need 2 function add and update the user socials with serialize array to string before insert to database here my code

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;
class User extends Model{
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'socials',
    ];

    public function getSocialsAttribute($value){
       return unserialize($value);
    }

    public function setSocialsAttribute($value){
        settype($value, 'array');
        $this->attributes['socials'] = serialize($value);
    }

}
```

and in my controller

```
$user_id = User::insert($request->post);
```

the post array with

```
array(
   'name'=>'A',
   'email'=>'Test@gmail.com',
   'socials'=> array(
     'facebook' => 'facebook.com',
     'twitter' => 'twiter.com'
   )
)
```

but the database does not serialize the data !

Comment: Where's your ```insertGetId``` function?

Comment: this is laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts

Comment: i change to insert and does not work too. :(

Comment: Can you check your database, check if the ```socials``` field is serialized.

Comment: not serialized . in socials column the text is Array !

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I think in order for you to use the mutator, you need to get an instance of the model and then set the attributes, then save.  I'm not convinced the mutator(s) will be applied when just passing your array of data to insertGetId.

Comment: @PeterJack, I updated my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it doesn't work on `insert` method. Try to use the `create` method to insert data to database.

```
$user = User::create($request->post);
```

Comment: That's weird, its working when I tried this. What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Thanks you , i update composer for lastest laravel eloquent and work !